# What does "get some life" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I made a comment and received the following reply:

> Ha ha! Go get some life you stupid.

I know that this is some kind of insult. But what does "get some life" exactly mean?

Comment: Was it "get a life" ?

Comment: @JoseK, it was probably _meant_ to be.

Comment: It's just another insult turned mostly ineffective by poor grammar.

Comment: The person who typed it is an idiot, or a non-English speaker.  Firstly, it's "get a life" (a common insult).  Secondly you don't use "stupid" as a noun: it should be for example ", you idiot!"  So, it's just an example of a sentence with **two major typos or errors**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a life | You have no life](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29978/get-a-life-you-have-no-life)

Comment: "Ha ha! Go get some life you stupid" has the makings of a reddit-style meme: irony (the person saying it is the one that looks stupid, but using it as a meme transcends this by a level) and, most importantly, mockery of poor grammar/foreign English speakers etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase is usually "get a life" rather than "get some life." The person who says this feels the person to whom it is said is wasting his or her time on something. Wikipedia has good examples:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_a_life_(idiom)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_a_life_%28idiom%29)

Implied in the taunt is to act normal (whatever that is!) or mainstream.

Comment: I understood the level of insult by your explanation. :) Thank you.

Comment: @Sagar: You're right in deciphering it as an insult, but he ended with "you stupid." That made his feelings clear - unfortunately for you.